# Sum of $x^k \cos(kx)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Is there a nice way to obtain a the following summation? $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k \cos kx$$
I have tried evaluating the real part of the sum $1+z+z^2 +...+z^n $ where $z=x(\cos x + i \sin x)$ Though realizing it and doing the algebra wasn't so neat, I eventually obtained an expression: $$\frac{x^{n+2} \cos (nx)-x^{n+1} \cos\bigl( (n+1)x \bigr)-x \cos x+1}{x^2-2x \cos x+1} $$ But I'm just wondering, is there a nicer way to do this / a nicer expression? Thanks

Comment: To me, this is the nicest expression that you could get.

Comment: That seems a nice way to do it. Remember that It is OK to answer your own question.

Comment: Search for "scale of relation"  in https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=ftp://kubacki.waw.pl/Hobson-Treatise_on_plane_trigonometry.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiu4eGE9-_hAhXMLI8KHQMdD8EQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw0-fPEg02cVKwlnKans9IBZ to reach at the same expression in an alternative way

Comment: A nicer expression: $\Im\left(\frac{-1+e^{i (n+1) x} x^{n+1}}{-1+e^{i x} x}\right)$